# How do I display ALL the data from Firebase in one list?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

we are trying to display all the data from a Firebase database in a list. This is our code so far:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
```

It would be great if anyone out there could help us!

Thanks...

Comment: I recommend checking out the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#child-events) or trying the [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/).

Answer (score 0):

```
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
    myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
            new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    //Get map of users in datasnapshot
                    collectPhoneNumbers((Map<String,Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue());
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    //handle databaseError
                }
            });

private void collectPhoneNumbers(Map<String,Object> users)
        {

        ArrayList<String> phoneNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

        List<ItemObjectVideo> allItems = new ArrayList<ItemObjectVideo>();
        //iterate through each user, ignoring their UID
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : users.entrySet()){

        //Get user map
        Map singleUser = (Map) entry.getValue();
        //Get phone field and append to list
        phoneNumbers.add((String)singleUser.get("url"));

        allItems.add(new ItemObjectVideo((String)singleUser.get("name")));

        }

        rcAdapter = new VideoRecyclerViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), allItems);
        rView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);
        rcAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code to get List of all the items from "message" reference in Firebase.

```
myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    long count = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                    if(count != 0 ){
                        for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            Message mesgObj =  data.getValue(Message.class);
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

You need to create Message Model class with fields from Firebase.